# Interpreting the logit results in terms of dollars

Tags: logistic, logit

If we regress the choice on some cost variables, then how would you interpret the meaning of the coefficients?
In this paper published in American Economic Review, link: http://economics.mit.edu/files/4513
Based on the estimation results in table 1, authors conclude that "individuals are willing to pay over $300 for full donut hole coverage" (it is an insurance plan which covers the Medicare donuts holes. it is a dummy variable with coefficient of 1.865)
I can not understand how the authors could come to that conclusion based on the logit estimation results! would you please help with that?

Comment: I'm guessing that they did something along the lines of 1.865/0.5218 = 3.57 (the latter being the coefficient on $100 of premium). Thought process seeming to be "if a person choose to take the donut option, how much more would they have to pay if we wanted the probability of choosing this plan to remain the same"

Comment: I like your way of thinking. You are asking: If a person's unobserved utility increases by 1.865 units with a donut option, then how much of increase in price creates enough dis-utility to offset that? and the answer is 3.57 or 357 dollars.  But then why have the authors said over 300, why not over 350? Specially since the cost differences is the main point here and they want to highlight the differences!

Comment: Dear @user50822 the link for the paper you cited is not available, can I have another link ? I'm facing the same problems for the interpretation of my data

Answer (score 2):

I glanced at the paper, and with that interpretation is also the phrase "controlling for the out of pocket cost consequences", which is another predictor in the model. It seems reasonable to look at the predictions with and without the dummy variable present, and in particular to compare the out-of-pocket cost values needed to produce the same predictions with the dummy variable set to 0 and to 1. In other words, compare the out-of-pocket consequences for two people equally likely to buy a policy, one without the coverage and one with it.

I'd have to read the whole paper to know for sure that's what they did, but that's my guess.

Comment: Please note that the out of pocket costs are not exactly known at the time of insurance purchase. However, premium is known. So I think we should look at the premiums and see how much of difference they make. Something like what mentioned in the comments to my original post. Or maybe we should consider both out of pocket costs and the premium together. If we do that then we have to solve one equation with two unknowns!